# Android SQLite Like query

Tags: sqlite, search, sql-like

The following Query works Fine in my app

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_FAULTREF,KEY_WORKNUM,KEY_ORIGNUM,KEY_REPBY,KEY_REPDATTIM,KEY_DESCRIPTION}, KEY_FAULTREF + "='" + strname+ "'", null,null, null, null, null);
```

strname is what I am searching for but it will only bring back records that EXACTLY match this

I want to modify so it brings back everything that CONTAINS strname (eg something like *strname*)

I tried the following but my app crashed

```
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_FAULTREF,KEY_WORKNUM,KEY_ORIGNUM,KEY_REPBY,KEY_REPDATTIM,KEY_DESCRIPTION}, KEY_REPBY + "LIKE %'" + strname+ "'%", null,null, null, null, null);
```

I know its the LIKE statement but any ides where im going wrong?

Your help appreciated

Mark

Comment: could you post the logcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%` wildcards must be part of the string:

```java
... + " LIKE '%" + strname+ "%'", ...
```

Please note that this code will blow up when the string contains a quote.
You should use parameters instead:

```java
db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE,
         new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_FAULTREF,KEY_WORKNUM,KEY_ORIGNUM,KEY_REPBY,KEY_REPDATTIM,KEY_DESCRIPTION},
         KEY_REPBY + " LIKE ?",
         new String[] { "%" + strname + "%" },
         null, null, null, null);
```